# Why is my regex redirection failing?

Tags: redirects

Source: `^help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/(.*)`

Target: `https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/help-msa/$1`

For example:

`https://help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa-overview.html`

should redirect to:

`https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/help-msa/msa-overview.html`

But it fails.

---

Initially I tried using the WordPress Redirection plugin. But now I am trying my `.htaccess`. I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help-msa\.publictalksoftware\.co.\uk
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.publictalksoftware\.co\.uk/help-msa/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it blows up the website. I know it is a Linux computer (the server).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I tried using curl. It says "Server: nginx/1.21.6".

Comment: nginx doesn't support .htaccess.  You'll need to edit your nginx configuration.  Is this the WordPress plugin you are using?  https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/  It says that it can export an nginx config file for you.  I would assume you have to install it manually though.

Comment: Then either nginx is in front of Apache as a reverse proxy, or Apache is configured to pretend to be nginx.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Actually, I think the htaccess redirects are replicated in the wordpress stored redirects. So I guess it was not using htaccess like you said.